# Why do Win10 Taskbar Icons sometimes "flash" for a second?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

I don't mean "blinking" as in notifying the user, I mean that the whole taskbar seems to do a "reload" of sorts, where the icons completely vanish for like half a second (leaving a blank taskbar) and then return.

Is this a background system update triggering a restart of `explorer.exe`?  I surely can't be the only one who has noticed/experienced this behavior.

Comment: If another task is using a lot of memory/CPU then explorer may have insufficient resources to redraw the taskbar in a timely fashion when requested to do so.

Comment: Plausible, but I don't think it's a load problem. Everything stays snappy and everything else displays correctly.

Comment: Does the taskbar seem to freeze or crash right before it blinks & reloads? Maybe that's what it's doing, just crashing

Comment: I don't think it's a crash. Notification area and such is not affected. Could be a redraw, but the thing is quite infrequent. I'm just curious really, it's not much of a nuisance.

Comment: I’ve seen the same behavior, and even wondered as to what Windows was doing. But it is so insignificant, I have never looked any further.

Comment: I agree, at least I'm not the only person who has observed it.

Comment: Simlar issue...https://superuser.com/questions/1322265/my-taskbar-in-windows-10-is-blinking-frequently

Answer (score 0):

If anything updates shell integration points (file associations etc.) then it may cause all shell windows to refresh, so that all files have the right icons, etc.

The desktop is just a shell view that's always "open", and that includes Taskbar etc. so that may be what's causing it to "blink"?